# Apache NIFI REST API (jwt) access via Apache Knox gateway

Tags: jwt, apache-nifi, apache-knox

I am looking for resources to configure Apache `KNOXTOKEN` service to access Apache NIFI REST API.

I already have `KNOXSSO` configured, and am able to access the NIFI UI through it. However, I could not find resources to make NIFI REST services securely accessible via Curl and JWT.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minor tweak to the other suggestion here...

When integrating with KnoxSSO, NiFi accepts the Knox JWT token in a cookie. By default, I believe this cookie is named `hadoop-jwt`. If you're trying to access NiFi Rest Api's using curl I believe you'd need to get the JWT value from Knox (or maybe by looking at the cookie in your browsers DevTools) and include it in a cookie in your curl requests.

If you include the Knox JWT token in an Authorization header the verification will fail. JWTs specified in the Authorization header must be tokens that NiFi generated/signed. To validated a token generated/signed by Knox, NiFi follows the Knox conventions.

Comment: Indeed! I did confirm this. 

So, i made a token request to  ´knoxtoken´ endpoint and used the token as ´hadoop-jwt´ cookie to interact with secure nifi-api, and this seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: After improving my understanding a bit more, I am able to get this to work by having two end points, one for KNOXSSO `-sso` and another for KNOXTOKEN `-jwt`, with two different access modes, but both redirecting to the same back end.

The -jwt endpoint expects a Authorization header with Bearer token, whereas -sso endpoint expects a cookie. I can say the first one is for api access, and the second one is for browsers.

Comment: how to get the knoxtoken via curl or rest api ?

Answer (score 2):

For other authentication mechanisms like SPNEGO or login identity providers, there are end-points like `/access/token` or `/access/kerberos` where you can obtain a token.

I don't think there is a way to do that for Knox since it requires the SSO workflow of being redirected a login page in your browser.

You would have to first authenticate to the NiFi UI via Knox SSO, and then use something like Chrome Dev tools to look in the browser's local storage and find the token that the NiFi UI has for the current user.

Then you can use that token to make API calls by passing it in the Bearer header like:

```
curl -k --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://<nifi-host>:<port>/nifi-api/flow/cluster/summary
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the knoxtoken via curl or rest api ?